# Change the Graphics properties of form Controls before Painting

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, graphics

I have a windows form with several controls, e.g. labels and buttons. When the form is painted, in the Paint event handler, I can use the `PaintEventArgs e` to:

```
private void Form_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;

    SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Test String", font, brush, 100, 100);
}
```

This way I can create a string using `Graphics.DrawString()` that conforms to the properties I set such as `TextRenderingHint`.

How can I change the `Graphics` properties for all the controls on the form, the labels and buttons etc, so that when they are painted/rendered they conform to the `Graphics` properties as I would like them to?

Specifically - I want to change the `TextRenderingHint` for controls on the form. I'd be equally happy if doing this for the `Form` itself including all controls was possible.

Comment: You are using the wrong method, use TextRenderer.DrawText() instead.  Disabling ClearType takes a much bigger weapon, ask at superuser.com

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant - but what I want is to be able to set the rendering property for a Control's text using `Graphics.TextRenderingHint`, and still use all the other control properties e.g. `Form.Label.Text = "Text";` in the windows form.  Do you know of a way?

Comment: Most controls in the toolbox draw text with operating system default settings.  So if you want them to look different then you have to change those settings.  Hopefully you realize that this is pretty pointless, your user won't do this.

Comment: @HansPassant thank you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I change the Graphics properties for all the controls on the form, the labels and buttons etc, so that when they are painted/rendered they conform to the Graphics properties as I would like them to?

You can't.

As Hans has said in the comments, the built-in controls for Winforms are mostly just thin wrappers around existing native Windows control classes. They will render using the current user settings, which are global for all applications.

Even if they weren't, there's the other problem that the `Graphics` instance being used is new for every `Paint` event, and each window-based control (i.e. most of them) gets a `Graphics` instance corresponding to the native `HDC` for that control's window's `WM_PAINT` event. There's no "global" `Graphics` instance that you could change, and which then would be reused for every `Paint` event.

Comment: Thanks @Peter and @Hans. I will have to draw the strings individually using `Graphics.DrawString()` or `TextRenderer.DrawText()` to obtain the result I'm after.